# Changing the hide show toggle effect?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have an element that works just fine with the following code. It's an object #obj1 that is hidden when loading the page, but appears when clicking on #obj2.

```
#obj1{
    position:fixed;  
    width:100px;  
    bottom:180px;
    right:100px; 
    display:none;
}

$("#obj1").hide();
$("#obj2").show();$('#obj2').toggle(function(){
$("#obj1").slideDown(function(){});
},function(){
$("#obj1").slideUp(function(){});
});
```

but I would like to have it like this:

```
$("#obj1").css({"opacity": "0","bottom": "180"})
$("#obj2").toggle(
function () {
$("#obj1").animate({"opacity": "1","bottom": "140"}, "slow");
},function () {
$("#obj1").animate({"opacity": "0","bottom": "180"}, "slow");
});
```

I would like it to fade in, but how do I add the animation to the first script? (animation ex: .animate({"opacity": "1","bottom": "140"}, "slow");)

Comment: you are confusing `css` and `jquery`. if you want to use opacity and fade in/out an object, you've got the code already. remove the `display:none` from your `css`

Comment: if I remove this part, the box will show up for 0.5 sec when loading the page. that's why I changed the old javascript with the new one (first script in post). i want to add the fade in from bottom 180-effect to be in the first script but i don't know how

Comment: So you want the second object to fade in, or slide up? or both?

Comment: I want #obj1 to do the same as it would do with the second script, with added display:none and hide/show (as it is).

Comment: I don't understand your very confusing. Ignore scripts just explain in words what you want to happen to each object when you click object 1

Comment: there's a box that is completely hidden at first, then there's a second box that you have to click on and the first box appears in a fade-in way

Comment: If i understand correctly, OP wants it to display hidden before the js is loaded and set it to be hidden. hence setting it `display:none` in the css

Answer (score 2):

Here is a super simple demo of fading in an element using CSS. You can use jQuery to add the class through a click event.

```
// HTML
<div id="myId" class="hide">
  This is div with myId
</div>

// CSS
.hide {
  display: none;
}
.myId {
  animation: fadein 2s;
}

@keyframes fadein {
  from { opacity: 0; }
  to   { opacity: 1; }
}

// JQUERY
$("#myId").removeClass("hide").addClass("myId");
```

You can see a working demo [here](http://codepen.io/Sacki2013/pen/dNBwKV). You'll just have to modify it to trigger on click of obj2 or where you like

EDIT - As per your comment above I have edited the pen, so now the element will be hidden on page load and then the class will be removed and the animation class added.

Answer (score 2):

You would be best keeping the styles within css, and just using js to change the state (add/remove a class). The way you have the javascript is passable, but it'd be better for the class to be toggled based on itself so they can't accidentally get out of sync:

```js
$('#obj2').on('click',function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  if($('#obj1').hasClass('js-on'))
    $('#obj1').removeClass('js-on');
  else
    $('#obj1').addClass('js-on');
});
```

```css
    #obj1{
        position:absolute;  
        width:100px;  
        bottom:10px;
        right:20px; 
        opacity: 0;
        
        background-color: yellow;
        padding: 1em;
        
        transition: .5s opacity, .5s bottom;
    }
    #obj1.js-on {
        opacity: 1;
        bottom: 40px;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="obj2" href="#">Click me</a>

<div id="obj1">Hi</div>
```

Comment: with both scripts nothing happens when clicking #obj2

Comment: @EnmaNii I typed it so fast, that I made some mistakes. You can try again with my edits.

Comment: please do try if you like

Comment: @EnmaNii I added a test snippet

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#obj1").hide();
$("#obj2").show();
});

$('#obj2').toggle(function(){
$("#obj1").slideToggle();
});
```

This will show `obj1` by sliding when `obj2` is pressed. To have it fade in instead Try,

```
$("#obj2").click(function () {
$("#obj1").fadeToggle("slow","swing");
```

This toggles `obj1` fading in and out.

reference:
http://api.jquery.com/fadetoggle/

Answer (score 1):

Slightly confused by the question, but here's my attempt at an answer: hope it helps

```js
$(".obj1").click(function(){
  $(".obj2").css('opacity', 0)
   .slideDown('slow')
   .animate(
    { opacity: 1 },
    { queue: false, duration: 'slow' }
  );
});
```

```css
.obj1 {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
  background: lightgrey;
}

.obj2 {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: red;
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="obj1">click me</div>
<div class="obj2"></div>
```